# Why does jquery mobile jumps to first page of the application?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

[image: application flowchart]

This is the flowchart of my application. It is just one html file with all the pages. 
When I try to go from page4 to page2 using

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#page2")
```

it shows me page2 and then immediately jumps to page1, but if I go to page1 and then go to page2 by changing url in browsers urlbar (index.html#page2) everything works correctly. This happens for any page I try to navigate this way from page4. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post some code or create a jsbin/jsfiddle of the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up splitting my app into different html files. Now everything works.